# httpd fails to load xDebug: The procedure entry point could not be located

Tags: php, apache, debugging, xampp, xdebug

after enabling xdebug through php.ini file, I recieve the following error frmo the httpd.exe process:

> The procedure entry point zend_unmangle_property_name_ex could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll.

I have uncommented the following 2 options:

- zend_extension = "C:\Users*****\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
- xdebug.remote_enable = 1 (this was set to 0 by default)

I'm using XAMPP 1.8.2 as my LAMP, running on Windows 7 SP1 (32-bit).
PHP version is 5.4.16.

Comment: php_xdebug.dll exist?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and yes it exists!

Comment: Does this error really effect anything though? Will it cause future problems for developing and testing e.g, when selecting data from the table?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using the wrong binary. Please refer to the Xdebug wizard at http://xdebug.org/wizard.php to find out which binary you need.

Comment: Perfect! Derick's solution worked for me! XAMPP 1.8.2. Probably it's a bug with that XAMPP release. In order to help, the XDEBUG version that worked was XDEBUG 2.2.3, PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (32 bit), [direct link](http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll)